# подскажите как задать маску

Tags: linux, ubuntu

помогите разобраться с генерацией пароля
Как задать маску например 123 это не изменная часть а дальше уже идет генерация пароля длинной 5 символов и что бы получить результат пример 123fhw2w

```
cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc 'a-z 0-9' | fold -w 5 | head -n 90
```

Comment: Есть же готовые `pwgen` и подобные.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Например так:

```bsh
cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc 'a-z0-9' | fold -w 5 | head -n 90 | sed s/^/123/
```

или так:

```bsh
cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc 'a-z0-9' | fold -w 5 | head -n 90 | awk '{print 123 $0}'
```

P.S. я убрал пробел из вашего фильтра. Вам же не нужен пароль с пробелом.

P.P.S. Вместо `a-z0-9` можно использовать `[:alnum:]` если нужны и большие буквы тоже.

Comment: Большое спасибо помогло cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc 'a-z0-9' | fold -w 5 | head -n 90 | sed s/^/123/

Comment: @strannik377 емли вам помог данный ответ - нажмите на галочку возле него